# Can you get full command line from process ID (including command line arguments, etc)?

Tags: command-line, pid

This question is in addition to the question asked here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163145/how-to-get-whole-command-line-from-a-process. On my system, the following command results in a PID (as expected):

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5 python3 main.py 1> out.txt 2> err.txt &
```

Now, the methods in the stack exchange link above provide many solutions. However, when trying these solutions, I only receive the following information:

```
python3 main.py
```

Is there a way to return the entire command line "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5 python3 main.py 1> out.txt 2> err.txt &", not just the portion "python3 main.py"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Assuming you're on a Linux system, you can find the individual bits, but you can't put it together.

Assume also that the process's PID is in `$pid`

The `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5` variable gets added to the *environment* of the python command. You can find it in `/proc/$pid/environ` but you can't tell which of those variables were specified on the command line: the user could have written

```sh
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5 
python3 main.py 1> out.txt 2> err.txt &
```

The file redirections are available in `/proc/$pid/fd`:

- `/proc/$pid/fd/1` is a symbolic link to `out.txt`
- `/proc/$pid/fd/2` is a symbolic link to `err.txt`

I don't know how to tell if a process is running in the background.

---

Since you're just interested in the environment: with bash

```sh
declare -A environ
while IFS='=' read -r -d '' var value; do
    environ["$var"]="$value"
done < /proc/$pid/environ

echo "process has CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE value ${environ[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. The environment was the primary portion I needed to see, so your solution works.